# Как удалить содержимое выражения начиная с его конца и только до последнего слеша?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть такая строка:

```
/ru/xxx/00202006050824096345
```

Необходимо на выходе получить после ее обработки вот такое значение:

```
/ru/xxx/
```

Часть выражения, которую необходимо удалить является динамической - поэтому точное содержимое после последнего слеша нам достоверное неизвестно.

Вопрос:
Как это возможно реализовать с помощью регулярного выражения или любым другим удобным способом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const str = '/ru/xxx/00202006050824096345';

const newStr = str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

console.log(newStr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Регулярное выражение для задачи

```
(.*\/)
```

Выражение также подходит для получение части пути без имени файла.